# How to add Image Slider in Custom WordPress Theme using WordPress Customizer API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a WordPress Theme so, I want to add a slider where user can select the image from WordPress Customizer and if they want to remove the image from slider then they just have to untick and the image will be removed from the slider.

I am following this article https://make.xwp.co/2016/08/12/image-gallery-control-for-the-customizer/ this works fine as I want but the issue is it shows the image as in gallery (I think it uses WordPress gallery shortcode) and I am using https://idangero.us/swiper/ so, I want to output image as a

```
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="someimage" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
    </div>
```

I have basic PHP Knowledge :/

in functions.php

```
function the_featured_image_gallery( $atts = array() ) {
    $setting_id = 'featured_image_gallery';
    $ids_array = get_theme_mod( $setting_id );
    if ( is_array( $ids_array ) && ! empty( $ids_array ) ) {
        $atts['ids'] = implode( ',', $ids_array );
        echo gallery_shortcode( $atts );
    }
}
```

in front-page.php

```
<?php the_featured_image_gallery(); ?>
```

is it possible to output the images as

```
<img src="blabla.jpg">
```

or is it possible to use custom html to output from

```
<?php echo gallery_shortcode( $atts ); ?>
```

?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With above Gallery plugin, values are saved as array of attachment ids. Using that ids, you can fetch image URL separately and render the markup as you require. Check following example.

```
<?php
$featured_image_gallery = get_theme_mod( 'featured_image_gallery' );
?>

<?php if ( ! empty( $featured_image_gallery ) ) : ?>
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <?php foreach ($featured_image_gallery as $image_id ) : ?>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id ) ); ?>" />
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: **not every hero wear a cape**    Thank You